# i need to add check box to every values in the realtimedatabase that is shown in the ui

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-listview, flutter-streambuilder, flutter-list-tile

i need to add check box to every values in the realtimedatabase that is shown in the ui this is an attendance system

in this program if i click on any check box all check box will be selected . i need to individually select and diselect

so i can add attentance according to the students who is present.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

class TestFile extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestFile({super.key});

  @override
  State<TestFile> createState() => _TestFileState();
}

class _TestFileState extends State<TestFile> {
  List<dynamic> items = [];
  List<dynamic> newlist = [];

  String? _selectedItem;
  bool _ischecked = false;
  DateTime _selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  List<String> myList = [];
  List<String> checklist = [];
  //!database reference and query

  final ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('attendance').child('studentlist');

  //!

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
        bottom: PreferredSize(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Padding(
                  // padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 5),

                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
                  child: DropdownButton<String>(
                    value: _selectedItem,
                    onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedItem = newValue;
                      });
                    },
                    items: <String>[
                      'period 1',
                      'period 2',
                      'period 3',
                      'period 4',
                      'period 5',
                      'period 6',
                      'period 7',
                    ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: value,
                        child: Text(value),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                    iconSize: 40,
                    underline: Container(),
                    iconEnabledColor: Colors.white, //Icon color
                    style: TextStyle(
                        //te
                        color: Colors.white, //Font color
                        fontSize: 20 //font size on dropdown button
                        ),
                    dropdownColor: Colors.purple,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 100,
              ),
              Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_month, color: Colors.white),
                    onPressed: () async {
                      final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
                        context: context,
                        initialDate: _selectedDate,
                        firstDate: DateTime(1900),
                        lastDate: DateTime.now(),
                      );
                      if (picked != null && picked != _selectedDate) {
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedDate = picked;
                        });
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 5),
              Text(
                DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(_selectedDate),
                style: TextStyle(
                    //te
                    color: Colors.white, //Font color
                    fontSize: 20 //font size on dropdown button
                    ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(30.0),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: ref.onValue,
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DatabaseEvent> snapshot) {
                List<bool> checked = List<bool>.filled(items.length, false);
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                } else {
                  Map<dynamic, dynamic> map =
                      snapshot.data!.snapshot.value as dynamic;
                  items.clear();
                  items = map.values.toList();
                  return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.snapshot.children.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, Index) {
                      return CheckboxListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            items[Index]['sname'],
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 19, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                          ),
                          value: _ischecked,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            setState(() {
                              _ischecked = val!;
                            });
                          });
                    },
                  );
                }
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(28, 0, 0, 0),
            child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
              onPressed: () {
                items.forEach((map) {
                  print(map.values.first);
                  newlist.add(map.values.first);
                });
                for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                  print(newlist[i]);
                }
                // Add your onPressed code here!
              },
              label: const Text('ADD'),
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
              backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The use-case is clear. What isn't working about the code that you shared. Specifically: If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?